# How to Make Collection Stop Calling Equals when Performing Collection.Remove

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Class `Test` which has a overriden method for "Equals" method and then I have a `TestCollection` class which is implemented using `ICollection<Test>` & `IEnumerable<Test>` in the Collection I have implemented Remove method which just removes the `item` from the current `TestCollection` object.

Whenever I class remove method for the `TestCollection` object, this internally calls "Equals" method which is overridden at `Test` class.

For one of my scenario, I do not want this Equals to be called, what are the other ways where I can remove the item from my collection without calling Equals

Below is the sample code for better understanding.

Test Class

```
   public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        private Collection<Test> _entities = new Collection<Test>();
        public bool Remove(Test item)
        {
            return this._entities.Remove(item);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Equals inside Test Object");

            return true;
        }
    }
```

TestCollection class

```
    public class TestCollection : ICollection<Test>, IEnumerable<Test>
    {
        public TestCollection() : base() { }

        private Collection<Test> _entities = new Collection<Test>();

        public TestCollection(IList<Test> entityList)
        {
            this._entities = new Collection<Test>(entityList);
        }

        public bool Remove(Test item)
        {
            return this._entities.Remove(item);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Equals inside Test Collection Object");
            return true;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the point here. `Equals` method is implementing the arithmetic relation of equivalence, like having attributes of being reflexive, symmetric and transitive. There are no two distinct ways to say that two objects are equal, you see?

Solution for you is to remove implementation of the `Equals` method. This method is intended to be overridden if and only if there is exactly one definition of equivalence for a class - like integer equality - there is exactly one way to test whether two integers are equal.

Also, that is the reason why `Remove` method does not accept an additional parameter such as an `IComparer` or `IEqualityComparer` - that wouldn't make sense.

On a related note: Entities should *never* override `Equals`. There is no equality relation (in mathematical terms) defined for objects that can change their state over time, and entity is defined as an object with lifetime. The trouble there is that you can pick two versions of the same entity and ask whether they are equal. Well, they are both equal (that is the same entity) and not equal (those are two versions of it). Therefore, `Equals` method is not the way to check equality of entities.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot.

The way that an item is removed from a list is done by doing an equality check for the item in question on each of the entries in the list.

There may be some way to do it, however, but I doubt it's a good practice, or even desirable code.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the list into another list that uses a custom `IEqualityComparer` implementation. Allow that comparer to have two different modes (pass through to object.Equals, or don't) and switch them before remove (and switch back afterwards).

Answer (score 0):

You could find the index of the item you want to remove (not use its Equal) and call `RemoveAt`